# Не могу развернуть простое Flask приложение на Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

1. Я создаю приложение в Pythonanywhere
2. Выбираю manual configuration
3. python3.4,
4. Клонирую из githab репозиторий (flasker) в консоли pythonanywhere
5. Перехожу в папку с проектом и устанавливаю виртуальное окружение:

   ```
   virtualenv --python=python3.4 myvenv
   source myvenv/bin/activate
   ```
6. Во вкладке Web прописываю путь к virtualenv `/home/MikeRu/mysite/flasker/myvenv`
7. в wsgi у меня прописанно это:

   ```
   import sys
   path = '/home/MikeRu/mysit/flasker'
   if path not in sys.path:
       sys.path.append(path)
   ```

Затем я обновляю приложение (Reload.MikeRu.pythonanywhere.com) и на странице отображается Hello World c

> This is the default welcome page for a PythonAnywhere hosted web application.
>
> Find out more about how to configure your own web application by visiting the web app setup page

Сам файл который я хочу  развернуть на pythonanywhere очень простой.
file name: server.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'My name is Mike'
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: вы должны запустить ваше приложение в файле wsgi, а вы только пути добавляете

Answer (score 2):

Я не увидел старт сервера Flask, возможно это поможет вам:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5001)
```

Должен будет запустится на `http://127.0.0.1:5001`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется или здесь опечатка?

```
path = '/home/MikeRu/mysit/flasker'
```

Должно быть

```
path = '/home/MikeRu/mysite/flasker'
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. Проблему эту помню.